Das Duden Bedeutungswörterbuch: Wie unterscheidet es sich von einem „normalen" Wörterbuch?
Ich habe vor kurzem das „Duden Bedeutungswörterbuch" gesehen.  Ich habe es nur online gesehen, dementsprechend kenne ich seinen Inhalt nicht, und verstehe nicht, inwiefern es sich von einem „normalen" Wörterbuch, z.B., dem „Deutsches Universalwörterbuch", unterscheidet.  Ich weiß, dass vor 10 Jahren jemand diese selbe Frage gestellt hat, aber ich habe die Antworten dort nicht besonders informativ gefunden. Danke für jede Information.

M.E. grenzt der Titel das Werk weniger von Werken wie dem Universalwörterbuch ab, sondern eher von anderen Verlagsangeboten. Das "Bedeutungswörterbuch" ist Teil einer Serie von 12 Nachschlagewerken zur deutschen Sprache. Jeder der 12 Bände hat einen anderen Schwerpunkt, neben Grammatik und Zeichensetzung unter anderem

Wortherkunft
Aussprache
Synonyme.

D.h. die Bezeichnung als "Bedeutungswörterbuch" grenzt diesen Band von den anderen der Reihe ab und markiert seine Zielsetzung, nämlich Erklärungen zu den aufgeführten Begriffen zu erhalten.
Hingegen überschneidet sich der Gegenstand des Wörterbuchs wohl weitgehend mit anderen, universell angelegten Wörterbüchern, die aber neben der Bedeutung der aufgeführten Begriffe regelmäßig noch Informationen zur Aussprache und zur Grammatik enthalten.

Eines vorweg: Der Dudenverlag hat viele Bücher mit unterschiedlichen Titeln, deren Inhalte sich jedoch ähneln oder sogar gleichen. Oftmals handelt es sich um Teile von Inhalten aus anderen Büchern des Dudenverlags, die minimal ergänzt wurden.


Das "Deutsche Universalwörterbuch" aus deinem Link hat 2160 Seiten und mehr als 500 000 Stichwörter.
Das "Bedeutungswörterbuch" hat 1184 Seiten und rund 20 000 Stichwörter.

Laut Vorwort im "Bedeutungswörterbuch" umfasst das Wörterbuch den kompletten Wortschatz des Goethe-Zertifikats B1. Im Vorwort des "Deutschen Universalwörterbuchs" steht hingegen nichts von Zertifikaten.
Das wäre die grobe Unterscheidung.

Auf der Webseite des Dudenverlags befinden sich Leseproben. Wenn du sie überfliegst, wirst du feststellen, dass die Wörter im "Bedeutungswörterbuch" alle Erklärungen zu haben scheinen. Im "Deutschen Universalwörterbuch" hingegen sind auch Wörter ohne Erklärung. Wahrscheinlich sind alle Wörter und Erklärungen aus dem "Bedeutungswörterbuch" auch im "Deutschen Universalwörterbuch" enthalten.
Das "Deutschen Universalwörterbuch" wird aufgrund seines Umfangs von 2160 Seiten deutlich schwerer und unhandlicher sein als ein Buch mit 1084 Seiten. Daher werden es die meisten Leute wohl eher zum gelegentlichen Nachschlagen benutzen.
Das "Bedeutungswörterbuch" ist anscheinend für zum schnelleren Nachschlagen der gängigsten Wörter im Alltag und insbesondere für Deutschlerner gedacht.
